# Synonym Request: visual-studio-code-extension to vscode-extensions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Alias request for [visual-studio-code-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code-extension) (4) → [vscode-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-extensions) (1,919)

Although the core tag for Visual Studio Code uses the fully spelled out version and [`vscode` aliases to `visual-studio-code`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio-code/synonyms), it seems as though most of the specific areas are prefixed with just `vscode-*`, presumably for brevity.

[image]

Comment: In this case, shouldn't we also create corresponding aliases for every `vscode-*` tag? (for discoverability consistency)

Answer (score 1):

I've retagged the remaining questions into [vscode-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-extensions). The other tag should go away in a day (the next time a maintenance script kicks in, usually around 3 AM UTC every day).

Comment: I added a synonym for good measure